# JSON Encoding custom class not calling overriden default

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have a class definition which I have based on json.JSONEncoder, within which I have overriden the default method.  Now when I call json.dumps on an instance of that class the default method is not being called?  Is there something I have missed?

In my example code I do not expect this to magically produce the serialized object but I would expect the `print("here")` to be executed.

```
import json


class MyClass(json.JSONEncoder):
    id = "myId"
    data = "myData"

    def default(self, o):
        print("here")


print ("Create instance")
obj = MyClass()
print("Serialize")
print(json.dumps(obj))
print ("and done")
```

I am quite new to Python, so apologies if this is something horribly obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further digging and tracing I think I have found the cause.  Part of the issue I think it my own misunderstanding of how this is intended to be used.

When calling `json.dumps` if you wish to use a custom encoder you need to specify the class of that encoder, otherwise `dumps` defaults to using the standard implementation of `JSONEncoder`.

```
json.dumps(obj, cls=MyEncoder)
```

My misconception was that by basing my class on `json.JSONEncoder` that `dumps` would simply recognise the instance as inheriting from `JSONEncoder` and call the override `default` method.  However this is not the case.

I have now created the logic in it's own class to encode my own class/types and when I call `json.dumps` I pass in that class name.

So I now have

```
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, MyClass):
            return {"id": obj.id, "data": obj.data}
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

And when I wish to serialize I use

```
json.dumps(object_to_serialize, cls=MyEncoder)
```

Which recognises my class and handles it, or passes on the encoding to the default encoder.